# How to save a WPF BitmapSource image to a file?

Tags: wpf, bitmapsource

In WPF, the [`System.Windows.Clipboard.getImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.getimage) function returns a [`BitmapSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource) object.  As a newbie in WPF coming from a WinForms background, its not clear to me how to save this image to a file.  What are the steps I must take?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to use an encoder (subclass of [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx)). For instance, to save it to the PNG format, you do something like that :

```
public static void SaveClipboardImageToFile(string filePath)
{
    var image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        encoder.Save(fileStream);
    }
}
```

By the way, note that there's [a bug in `Clipboard.GetImage`](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/). It shouldn't be a problem if you just save the image to a file, but it will be if you want to display it.

---

EDIT : the bug mentioned above seems to be fixed in 4.0

Comment: This does not compile on my machine. BitmapFrame.Create parameters are URI or stream, not image :\

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia This method does exist in WPF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615993(v=vs.110).aspx. What kind of app are you making?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I did a fast proof of concept app with WinForms.

Comment: This does not work when the saved request comes from a different thread.

Answer (score 2):

This clears up the BitmapFrame.Create issue that you have.

```
public static void SaveClipboardImageToFile(string filePath)
{
    //var image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    BitmapSource image = (BitmapSource)Clipboard.GetImage();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        //encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image As BitmapSource));
        encoder.Save(fileStream);
    }
}
```