# how to get path of new from steam?

Tags: c#, image, stream, resize, image-resizing

I have a image `icon.png` and i am using FFImageloading plugin to re-size image. Than I am converting Stream to ImageSource and displaying the result. works fine

How to save re-size image stream into cache folder and get path of it? can someone point me in right direction plz

```
var stream = await ImageService.Instance.LoadFile("icon.png")
         .DownSample(width: 200)
         .AsPNGStreamAsync();

ImageSource myImageS= ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
DisplayImage.Source = myImageS;
```

I can use `File.Move` but i would need path of stream content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to save it back to the disk. The current code does not save it yet. You can save it using something like:

```
// Save the file 
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("icon2.png", FileMode.Create))
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(myImageS));
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}
```

Note: I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900564/2352507) for help with this.

Comment: i see, thanks for letting me know my code wasn't saving them image. I am just a lil confoused on how to save a image. for ex: what is icon2.png? is this random name of new image?

Comment: Correct, icon2.png was just some random name I picked. You could use anything here you like, even the original filename if you like.  You can just add this code under your existing code.

Comment: Hopefully it saves in the same path. If not you might need to capture the path then add the path to that location.

Comment: it makes sense, it is working fine now. thanks