# How to write image to clipboard programmatically on Windows (using powershell or other tools)?

Tags: windows, powershell, clipboard

I know on Windows, powershell `Get-Clipboard -format image` outputs the clipboard image.

But the `Set-Clipboard` command doesn't seem to support image.

Also, how to transform the output from `Get-Clipboard -format image` to buffer or base64 string?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567806/use-powershell-to-save-a-system-windows-interop-interopbitmap-to-disk/72568111#72568111

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
Get-ChildItem <Image Path> | Set-Clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked and more native

one line code:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage([System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("string filename"))
```